# jquery/rails call back a function to refresh datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I  got datatables up and running, beautifully along with the nice jquery-ui as in the front page of datatables.

However, the main issue I'm having though is that I suck at CoffeeScript/JS

I'm trying to reload datatables every 1 second but don’t see any request coming into the webserver and hence no refreshes on the web page itself.

Here's my code:

app/assets/javascripts/comments.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#comments_id').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    bProcessing: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#coments')
  setInterval('$("#comments_id").dataTable().fnReloadAjax()', 3000);
```

It appears the setInterval callback is not being executred to redraw the table with fnDraw.

It seems I have the setInterval coding wrong.

Here is my the code in my app/view/comments/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing comments</h1>

<table id="comments_id" class="display">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>String</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.string %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: <grin> One up for complete honesty! </grin>

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `sAjaxSource` and instead of just redrawing the data table you should reload it:

`.dataTable().fnReloadAjax();`.

See: [JQuery DataTables - AJAX Reloading Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043076/jquery-datatables-ajax-reloading-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: Hiya Ghommey: So I set sAjaxSource: $('#comments'). In the comment view, I have the table defined as follows <table id="comments_id" class="display". and I edited the last line in jQuery as follows...setInterval('$("#comments_id").dataTable().fnReloadAjax()', 3000);....I'm still not seeing requests being pushed through the server or any ajax reloads being done..... V_V....Thanks

Comment: sAjaxSource has to be a url